# SpriteKit - How to make applyImpuse always the same force

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on a game where my hero will be able to jump. I can do that with applyImpulse easy enough. The problem I'm having is I want him to be able to double jump and sometimes triple jump. When he does a double jump, sometimes he goes REALLY high. Way higher than the first jump. I want his jump to be equal each time he does it and I want him to go down at the same speed that he went up.

I am using this for the jump:

```
[hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 120)];
```

I don't have a lot of physicsWorld defined which might be my issue. I have the following set:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -10.0);
```

I've tried different gravity's but it comes out the same.

My hero has the following properties:

```
hero.physicsBody.friction = 1.0f;
hero.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0f;
hero.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.1f;
hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
hero.physicsBody.mass = 0.2f;
```

Is there something here that would be causing my issue? Something I'm missing or I should try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how physics works. A way around it is to reset hero's velocity right before you apply the second impulse.

```
hero.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
[hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 120)];
```

Comment: I didn't set a velocity on him before. Do I need to reset it after the impulse?

Comment: hero always has some velocity, you're affecting it when you apply the first impulse. Each impulse is affected by an object's current velocity, which is why applying a second impulse isn't consistent with the first impulse. You don't want to reset after the impulse because that would cancel it out.

Comment: Would it be best to set this property with the rest of my properties and not every time applyImpulse is called?

Comment: Properties are constant, velocity never is, so you have to reset it every time you apply an impulse.